# UK courier for delivering covid-19 test (fit-to-fly requirements)

Tags: uk, covid-19, mail

Are there any reliable couriers in the UK to deliver my (used) coronavirus test kit? The most common ones like DHL and DPD do not accept them, and Royal Mail deliveries are often delayed.

Travellers to many countries require a negative coronavirus test result (ie. fit-to-fly requirements) before you depart. Depending on the country, the test must be taken within 48h, 72h, or 96h before the departure time. So this is also a time sensitive parcel (delivery by 9am next day would be best).

Comment: I'm not certain it has anything to do with Traveling.

Comment: Don’t the test providers give guidance on how to return them for processing?

Comment: @Traveller Yes, test providers typically recommend using Royal Mail 1st class to return the test... but they also note that there can be severe disruptions to the service during the pandemic, and suggest using a private courier arranged at my own expense

Comment: Travelling in person to somewhere to get swabbed is probably safest - are you near any branches of Boots that offer the testing, or near any of the international airports offering on-site testing?

Comment: @Gagravarr Boots says they return the test results typically within 48h. London heathrow for example also offers testing and returns results within 48h or the next day. For peace of mind (especially for travellers with tight timeframes) it would be best to get same-day results or within 24h.

Comment: For same-day results you need to get the sample taken somewhere with a lab, and certainly not any kind of post-in thing! Probably means a trip to London though, that's the only place I've heard of with in-house labs for quick turnaround

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.